# Computationally inexpensive comparison between two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a symmetric $100\times100$  matrix, $A$ , with elements $A_{ij} < 100 $. I have to find whether this matrix is equal to or similar to another matrix $B$ of the same configuration. As these matrices are happening at a different point in time, I can't have an element by element comparison. I am looking to create something like base or invariant from the first matrix, store it, find the same base or invariant from the second matrix, and then compare whether they are equal or not.

I want to know if there is any way to do that in a computationally feasible way. As per Spectral theorem, is there a way to find invariant factors with less computation?

Comment: Diagonal form? Its invariants under similarity? Like its characteristic or minimal polynomial? Its Sylvester form?

Comment: Compute the eigenvalues and only compare these.

Comment: What do you mean by similar? $A = C^{-1}BC$ for some $C$?

Comment: @martycohen By similar i meant all or almost all elemnts in matrix A and B are same. For the notation you specified I have to calculate eigen vauues to conceive C right?

Comment: @justwanttogetbetter I dont understand those points.. Do they belongs to some form of similarity checking metric?

Comment: @justwanttogetbetter so what they mean by "similar" .. I need even the positional similarity of element values ie A0,0 and B0,0 should be equal or close.. For  example A(2X2)={ 2,2,2,2} and B(2X2)={2,2,10,2) are more dissimilar than same A and  B(2X2)={1,1,1,1}

Comment: Yeah I get what you mean

Answer (score 1):

As you have symmetric matrices with real entries, their eigenvalues are real numbers.

This does not mean you have to compute the eigenvalues. Your objective to use invariants such as trace, determinant, etc. is very reasonable.

I would even advise you to restrict your investigations at first to the trace $\sum_i A_{ii}$ ; it is very light, computionaly speaking (unlike the determinant) and work in this way:

- Compute and store the trace of each matrix.
- Once this has been done, look for pairs $(A,A')$  of matrices with the same trace (or maybe whose trace differ by less than a very small amount...),
- compare now those matrix pairs :

  a) entrywise for the case $A=A'$.

  b) If $A \neq A'$, they can be similar ; I would advise then to provide a second filter by testing if $\det(A)=\det(A')$. If it is not the case, you can reject the pair, otherwise, now and only now, you can  proceed to the computation of both spectra and test whether they are the same.

Comment: As far as I understood, OP meant that he can always only access one of the matrices. This excludes only storing the trace and if necessary checking all entries. Because the entries must have been stored too then.

Comment: @M. Winter I hadn't understood it in that way. The best would be to have an echo from him now...

Comment: . Sorry for the delayed respose. I can always access only one  of the matrix at a time. Element by element comparison is not feasible in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The identity of a symmetric matrix (up to similarity) is completely determined by its set of *real* eigenvalues. Therefore, the best you can do to detect a similar matrix with certainty is to compute and store all 100 eigenvalues $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_{100}$ (with multiplicities), e.g. in increasing order to simulate unordered tuples, and then compare these 100-vectors with each other instead of the 10,000 matrix entries.

---

**Another idea**

I just realized that there might be other sets of invariants too. Note that it always have to be 100 of them, though.

One idea I had is that you can compute the [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial) of $A$, normalize it and store its 100 non-trivial (e.g. non-leading) coefficients. This is (if you know how to do it) the effort of computing *one* determinant. Since the characteristic polynomial uniquely determines the eigenvalues, storing it is an alternative to computing them. You only have to compare the coefficients of these polynomials to compare the matrices.

This has several advantages and disadvantages compared to the eigenvalue-approach. One advantage is (depending on your use case) that if your matrix only has integer components, then these coefficients will be rational number, hence you do not need (rounding error prone) floating-point arithmetic. A disadvantage might be stability and the size of the resulting number. Since one of them is the *determinant* of your matrix, it will be **huge** (in the order of $10^{100}$). You will therefore need special data-types or you again use floating-point arithmetic with double (or more) precision.

There might be other sets of invariants which balance this effort of computation and stability. But I am not familiar with any of them. Note however, that the asymptotic complexity of computing a determinant is usually higher than that of computing eigenvalues. Whether it is better for your case, you have to find out yourself.

Comment: does same eigen values of two matrix is a sufficient condition that they are same? is there any theorem or proof  for this?

Comment: @DileeshDil "All eigenvalues are the same" is a sufficient (and necessary) condition for *symmetric* matrices to be *similar*. This is some fundamental result from eigenvalue theory: two matrices are similar if they have the same Jordan normal form, which in the case of symmetric matrices is a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues on the diagonal. Some search terms are: eigenvalues, spectral theorem, Jordan normal form, diagonalizable matrix.

Comment: So according to you,  Jordan normal form or anything that deal with eigen values are the only way. But calculating eigen vector in python took almost 0.14 seconds. For the particular application which I am dealing with this time is HUGE.. That is why I asked for a computationally feasible solution . Or at least a solution that give me "the cange from the other" with out checking all elements

Comment: @DileeshDil This is the only way to with 100% certainty detect similar matrices without false positives. You have to to know what is more important to you, performance or accuracy. If you go with performance, then the other posts might give your faster heuristic methods. Note that I not said you should compute the eigen vectors, but only the eigenvalues. Maybe storing the whole 10,000 entry matrix is also not a no-go for you, especially in combination of the other answers. Maybe you should consider using an other language if performance is your concern.

Comment: @DileeshDil I updated my answer with another idea.

Comment: user @loup blanc  has suggested the idea to use characteristic equation.  What would be the theoretical proof of it?

Comment: @DileeshDil Proof of what? All of this is evident from a bit of fundamental eigenvalue theory.

Answer (score 0):

It's an  ill-posed problem. If we know only an approximation of the $(A_{i,j})$, then (eventually) we can only say that $ A, B $ are almost similar. Then we assume that the $(A_{i,j})$ are exactly known.

In these conditions, (since the considered matrices are diagonalizable), at each step,  just store the 100 coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

There are randomized algorithms that do the job in $O(n^3)$ operations in $\mathbb{R}$. If the $(A_{i,j})$ are integers, there is an algorithm that does the job in essentially $O(n^{3.5}\log(||A||))$ bit operations (I don't write the terms in $\log(n)$ or $\log(\log(||A||))$).

When $A\in M_{100}(\mathbb{Z})$, the time of calculation with Maple (which is a very slow software) is $0"14$. About storing coefficients (at each step), $\approx 60$ amongst the $100$ coefficients are in the segment $[10^{100},10^{260}]$; that is, each storage contains $\approx 14000$ (decimal) digits.

Comment: Value of (Ai,j)  is  exactly known. But the for matrix B,  (Bi,j <100) .(It can approximate any value below 100). . Is there any proof that coefficients of a characteristic polyomial can be used to compare two matrixes for their similarity?